# Looking for math function for finding highest possibile sum

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a set of 4-digit numbers from which I have to find the largest possible sum consisting of a maximum of 5 items not exceeding 24 thousand but not less than 21 thousand. Even though it sounds trivial and I do it by hand without any problems (the collections are not very numerous) I can't get it over my head to transfer it to a spreadsheet.

@edit
Ex. Set of data {4785,4890,5030,5790,6020,3230,4500,5000,4550,2300,5400,5350.....}

Comment: How do you do it by hand?

Comment: Hehe u know calculator and trial and error test is it important for u?

Comment: A small remark: "*but not less than 21 thousand*" part has no meaning. Because when you find the largest sum that is less than 24 thousand, it is either larger than 21 thousand or not.

Comment: Cem well yes and no. Sometimes set of data i got make it impossible to reach 21k so i need to know that so this is why i need this condition.

Comment: Yes, such a macro is not very difficult. You need to find the elements that add up to 22500 ± 1500. How many elements have turned out (five or more) can be determined manually. Now I'll look in the archives ...

Comment: Can values be used more than once? For example, 4785 * 5 = 23925.

Comment: @JimK No every value can be used only once

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer to handle that requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tools -> Solver* works for the values in your example. Here is the spreadsheet I used, with data in cells A2 through A13.

```
   Data    Chosen Rows Chosen Values   Calculation
   4785    5           5790            24000
   4890    7           3230
   5030    4           5030
   5790    12          5400
   6020    10          4550
   3230                                      
   4500                                      
   5000                                      
   4550                                      
   2300                                      
   5400                                      
   5350
```

The formula for `C2` is `=INDIRECT("A"&B2)`, filled down to C6. Then `D2` is simply `=SUM(C2:C6)`.

Here are the Solver settings.

[image: solver settings]

Also under *Options*, use the non-linear solver. Specify that variables are integer (this was required even though I added integer as a limiting condition) and non-negative.

**EDIT**:

> every value can be used only once

In that case, enter the following as an array formula in cell B8, explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38286032/5100564.

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(B2:B6;B2:B6))
```

Then add another limiting condition to the solver: `$B$8 => 5`.

Comment: Can you please explain to me first two call reference why is it value 2 and 13. I asume its for specific set of number in our example if yes then first value should always be 2 and sencond value can vary from min 5 (minimum required value) to well infinite or around 50-100 to be precise sometimes.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Change it to be higher if needed. But making it too high, say for example 1 million, would probably make the solver very slow.

Comment: Ah i figured it out :) Can you please help me with the problem that I dont want to use same variable twice? Im trying to do that for 4 hours but didnt know exacly where to start. In Solver there is no such function so it should probably made in C row but dunno how. Please give me a hint first so i can try to resolve that by myself.

Comment: I was working on that while you were commenting. :) See edited answer.

Comment: Everything seems to be working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help, now I'm getting to python and I'm planning to transfer it to the application. There is still a lot to add but this is the basic model I needed to visualize.

Answer (score 1):

If you organize the data in descending order and calculate the partial sums, then the recursive algorithm very quickly finds a solution (of course, if it exists)

```
Option Explicit     

Dim valRes() As Boolean
Dim indRng() As Long
Dim rngSum() As Currency
Dim ttlSum() As Currency
Dim lowA As Long, upA As Long

Rem The function returns an array of boolean values, 
Rem in which True marks the line numbers in the rngSumIsh range,
Rem from which the total can be collected with an acceptable error of no more than delta,
Rem or completely False - "No result"
Function findSet2(total As Double, rngSumIsh As Variant, Optional delta) As Variant
Dim restSum As Currency
Dim i As Long
Dim firstEl As Long, lastEl As Long
    If IsMissing(delta) Then  delta = 0
    If Not IsArray(rngSumIsh) Then
        findSet2 = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If delta < 0 Then
        findSet2 = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    Call createWorkArrays(rngSumIsh)
    restSum = total
    findSet2 = valRes
    If restSum - delta < ttlSum(upA) Then Exit Function
    If restSum - delta > ttlSum(lowA) Then
        For i = lowA To upA
            valRes(i, 1) = True
        Next i
        findSet2 = valRes
        Exit Function
    End If

    Call getNextElem(lowA - 1, restSum, delta, firstEl, lastEl)
    If firstEl <= lastEl Then ' There is a suitable element
        For i = firstEl To lastEl
            If Abs(restSum - rngSum(indRng(i))) <= delta Then
                valRes(indRng(i), 1) = True
                Exit For
            ElseIf isfindSet2(i, restSum - rngSum(indRng(i)), delta) Then
                valRes(indRng(i), 1) = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    findSet2 = valRes
End Function

Function isfindSet2(curIndex As Long, restSum As Currency, delta As Currency) As Boolean
Dim i As Long, firstEl As Long, lastEl As Long
    isfindSet2 = False
    Call getNextElem(curIndex, restSum, delta, firstEl, lastEl)
    If firstEl <= lastEl Then
        For i = firstEl To lastEl
            If Abs(restSum - rngSum(indRng(i))) <= delta Then
                valRes(indRng(i), 1) = True
                isfindSet2 = True
                Exit For
            ElseIf isfindSet2(i, restSum - rngSum(indRng(i)), delta) Then
                valRes(indRng(i), 1) = True
                isfindSet2 = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Function

Sub createWorkArrays(arrSum As Variant)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim tmpVal As Long
    lowA = LBound(arrSum)
    upA = UBound(arrSum)
    ReDim rngSum(lowA To upA)
    ReDim valRes(lowA To upA, 1 To 1)
    ReDim indRng(lowA To upA)
    ReDim ttlSum(lowA To upA)
    For i = lowA To upA
        rngSum(i) = arrSum(i, 1)
        indRng(i) = i
        valRes(i, 1) = False
    Next i
Rem Let's "sort" the rngSum array (actually sort the array of its indices)
    For i = lowA To upA - 1
        For j = i + 1 To upA
            If rngSum(indRng(i)) < rngSum(indRng(j)) Then
                tmpVal = indRng(i)
                indRng(i) = indRng(j)
                indRng(j) = tmpVal
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ttlSum(upA) = rngSum(indRng(upA))
    For i = upA - 1 To lowA Step -1
        ttlSum(i) = ttlSum(i + 1) + rngSum(indRng(i))
    Next i
End Sub

Rem The procedure tries to find the next matching element in the rngSum array - firstEl starting from the next one after curIndex.
Rem A qualifying element is one whose sum adjusted for delta does not exceed the remainder.
Rem The last matching element in the ttlSum array is also searched for - lastEl
Rem (the amount of the remaining items is not less than the remainder)
Rem Returns the indices of found elements
Sub getNextElem(curIndex As Long, restSum As Currency, delta As Currency, ByRef firstEl As Long, ByRef lastEl As Long)
Dim i As Long 
    firstEl = upA + 1
    lastEl = lowA - 1
    If curIndex < upA Then
        For i = curIndex + 1 To upA
            If restSum + delta >= rngSum(indRng(i)) Then
                firstEl = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        For i = firstEl To upA
            If restSum - delta <= ttlSum(i) Then
                lastEl = i
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

If you need more remarks to understand the code, see the full version of the code in this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghpelahm0wwneje/Highest%20possibile%20sum.ods?dl=0)

[image: Result for your example]